# Assigning scores to bullet holes on a simple ringed target

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am currently working on a project to detect and score bullet holes on a simple ringed target.
The code I have now assigns the holes a score based on the centre of the contour. This is the [Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMsnh.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMsnh.png) I am using

If a contour overlaps the boundary of a higher zone I want it to be assigned the higher score, regardless of where the centre is. An example is shown below:

[image: 2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5dm3.jpg)

The code and output of my program are shown below, where the scores are assigned respective of the centre rather than overlapping boundaries:

[image: Failed attempt]

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

def centroid(contour):
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    cx = int(round(M['m10']/M['m00']))
    cy = int(round(M['m01']/M['m00']))
    centre = (cx, cy)
    return centre

def getScore(scoreboundaries, HoleDist): #function to assign a score to each hole

    score = 0

    if scoreboundaries[0]>HoleDist:
        score = 10
    for i in range(1, len(scoreboundaries)):
        if scoreboundaries[i-1]<=HoleDist<scoreboundaries[i]:
            score = len(scoreboundaries) - i
    return score


default = cv2.imread("3.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(default,(640,640))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

v_mask = cv2.inRange(v, 0, 155)

cnts = cv2.findContours(v_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for c in cnts:

    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 10000: 
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        area_max = cv2.contourArea(c) 
        
radius_max = np.sqrt(area_max / np.pi)
section_size = radius_max / 9

centre_v_mask = cv2.inRange(v, 215, 255)
cnts = cv2.findContours(centre_v_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 10:
        centre_coords = centroid(c)
       
h_mask = cv2.inRange(h, 0, 30)
h_mask = cv2.medianBlur(h_mask, 11)
cnts = cv2.findContours(h_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

holes = []
HoleDists = []


scoreboundaries = []
for i in range(1,10): #calculate other rings
    
    cv2.circle(img, centre_coords, int(i*(section_size)), (255, 0, 0), 1)
    scoreboundaries.append(int(i*(section_size)))

for c in cnts: #plot bullet holes

    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 1:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        pts =[(x, y), (x+w, y), (x, y+h), (x+w, y+h)]

        centre_holes = centroid(c)
        pts.append(centre_holes)

        pointscore = 0
        for pt in pts: 
            X = pt[0]
            Y = pt[1]
            
            HoleDist = np.sqrt((X-centre_coords[0])**2 + (Y - centre_coords[1])**2)
            HoleDists.append(HoleDist)
            score = getScore(scoreboundaries, HoleDist)

            if score>pointscore:
                pointScore = score

        cv2.circle(img, (centre_holes), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        

        cv2.putText(img, "Score: " + str(pointScore), (centre_holes[0] - 20, centre_holes[1] + 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('frame', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I was wondering where I am going wrong. All help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic Python bug. You capitalize `pointscore` at the lines:

```
pointScore = score
cv2.putText( img, "Score: " + str(pointScore) ....
```

So you're really just using the last score you saw since `pointscore` is always `0` and `pointScore = score`.

Here's the picture with those two typos fixed. Also bear in mind that OpenCV contours are just a set of points that connect together. You can use the same scoring code to iterate through the contour points if you want.

[image]

If you want to swap to using contour points it's a small change.

Change this:

```py
for pt in pts: 
    X = pt[0]
    Y = pt[1]
```

To this:

```py
for pt in c:
    pt = pt[0] # contour points have an extra pair of brackets [[x,y]] 
    X = pt[0]
    Y = pt[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your suggestion! Would you be able to demonstrate this? I understand the logic behind it but I can not seem to implement it. I am very new to python opencv so I am still getting used to the syntax. Thank you in advance